# What is "Segmentation fault (core dumped)?"

Tags: c

I am trying to write a C program in linux that having sqrt of the argument, Here's the code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(char *argv[]){
    float k;
    printf("this is consumer\n");
    k=(float)sqrt(atoi(argv[1]));
    printf("%s\n",k);
    return 0;
}
```

After I type in my input at the "shell> " prompt, gcc gives me the following error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump

Comment: wrong format string used you need `%f`, not `%s`

Comment: Try `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Comment: Also, turn on your compiler warning messages, they would have told you lots of things.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

"Segmentation fault" means that you tried to access memory that you do not have access to.

The first problem is with your arguments of `main`. The `main` function should be `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` (or, equivalently, `int main(int argc, char **argv)`), and you should check that `argc` is at least `2` before accessing `argv[1]`.

Also, since you're passing in a `float` to `printf` (which, by the way, gets converted to a `double` when passing to `printf`), you should use the `%f` format specifier. The `%s` format specifier is for strings (`'\0'`-terminated character arrays).

Comment: I was taught that it should be `int main(int argc, char** argv)` instead of `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. Though the way you put it is correct,` char\*\*` is the actual 'correct' way to do it because it represents a pointer to a pointer to a character.

Comment: @WillHopkins The standard says that `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or equivalent are acceptable, with the footnote after "equivalent" saying " Thus, `int` can be replaced by a typedef name defined as `int`, or the type of `argv` can be written as
`char ** argv`, and so on."
So really, it's a matter of style.
(see 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup)

Comment: Yeah, I just thought I'd mention it because that's what I use:)

Comment: Could you please develop a bit more "and you should check that argc is at least 2 before accessing argv[1]" to help me understand what it means? Thanks!

Comment: @Ni-Ar `argc` is how many values are in `argv`. So before you do anything with `argv[1]`, you need to ensure `argc >= 2`