# How can i Install mu micropython editor on linux?

Tags: python, editor, mu

I am developing something on Micro:Bit but I am not able to install MU editor on a Linux machine.

Can someone provide the steps for installing mu editor on a Linux machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Download the latest Mu](http://codewith.mu/)
2. `cd the_folder_where_mu_was_downloaded`
3. `chmod +x mu-0.9.12.linux.bin`
4. `sudo usermod -a -G dialout username`
5. `./mu-0.9.12.linux.bin`

[More information available at the source of the instructions](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-get-mu-editor-microbit-up-running-ubuntu-linux-sakari-castr%C3%A9n/)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for responding back. i am getting this .cd /home/anish
anish@anish-Vostro-1450:~$ chmod +x mu_2017-06-21_18_07_master_3202867.bin
anish@anish-Vostro-1450:~$ sudo usermod -a -G dialout Anish
[sudo] password for anish: 
usermod: user 'Anish' does not exist
anish@anish-Vostro-1450:~$ sudo usermod -a -G dialout anish
anish@anish-Vostro-1450:~$ ./mu_2017-06-21_18_07_master_3202867.bin
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
anish@anish-Vostro-1450:~$

Comment: [See this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19641654/4889267) Maybe try running your `.bin` as `sudo`?

Comment: getting the same Segmentation fault with System problem detected :(